# Play AudioStreamer in Background mode in iPhone app

Tags: ios4, audio-streaming, audiostreamer

I was faced with the one problem.

AuidoStream doesn't works in Background mode.

So I added the "Required background modes" in Info.plist and selected "App plays audio".

But AuidioStream doesn't works in background mode yet.

In original, I had a sample AudioStream code.

I changed the some UI. origin audiostreamer works in background mode after i did like above.

But the audiostreamer that i changed some UI doesn't works in background mode.

I can't guess why this happens.

Please let me know if you know about this.

Thanks

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem it was solved by using `Required background modes` in Info.plist and `App plays audio`. make sure you have not stopped the stream explicitly on `viewDidUnload` or `viewWillDisappear` kind of methods